# Shortest distance between two curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $C_1= \{ (x, y) \in \mathrm{R}^2 : y = x^2 +1 \}$ and $C_2= \{ (x, y) \in \mathrm{R}^2 : x = y^2 +1 \}$, find the points which minimize distance between $C_1$ and $C_2$. What I tried is: we know that a generic point for $C_1$ is $(x, x^2 + 1)$, while a generic point for $C_2$ is $(y^2 + 1, y)$. It is pretty clear that the two curves don't intersect, so the distance between a generic pair is:

$$||(x, x^2+1) - (y^2 + 1, y)||$$

Which for extreme finding is the same as

$$f(x, y) = ||(x - y^2 - 1, x^2+1 - y)||^2$$

Trying to find the critical points means we have to find out what the gradient is:

$$\nabla f(x, y) = (4x^3 - 2y^2 - 4yx +6x - 2, 4y^3 - 2x^2 -4yx +6y -2)$$

Hence, I'm looking for the roots of:

$$2x^3 - 2y^3 -y^2 +x^2 +3x-3y = 0$$

It is pretty clear that $(x, x) : x \in R$ is always a solution. However, I'm not sure there aren't any other roots. Is there any other method or some other way to solve this problem?

Comment: try to parameterize as [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%7B%7Bt%2Ct%5E2%2B1%7D%2C%7Bt%5E2%2B1%2Ct%7D%7D%2C%7Bt%2C-2%2C2%7D ]

Comment: Looks like at the closet point you have the the derivatives are parallel, or something similar along those lines. This leads to $x \approx 1.056$, which seems plausible from the plots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use the fact that the curves are reflections in the line $x=y$: that means it's sufficient to find the point closest to that line (on either curve). The point closest to that line on the curve $y=x^2+1$ has slope $1$ (where a line parallel to $x=y$ is tangent).

Comment: I'm worried about the stringency of such a method. Although the statement is fairly intuitive, could you provide any formal proof to the statement above?

Comment: @Julián, the first sentence is intuitive enough? That leaves the second: we want to prove the point closest to $x=y$ is where a tangent line is parallel to $x=y$. Since the graph doesn't touch $x=y$ and is continuous, there's a closest point; since it's everywhere nonlinear and smooth, that's a tangent point. (That's still a bit of handwaving, but should suffice, I hope.)

Comment: The problem is not about understanding, the problem is that I'm preparing for a final exam in which they ask to prove anything not yet proven in class, hence I'm trying to avoid hand-waving as much as I can

Answer (score 1):

Factorize with (x-y). If you try to solve the equation in terms of x, let's say, you' ll find that it cannot have any real solutions, which leads us to the result that you have already found: the only solution is y=x.

Comment: After factoring with (x-y), you get $(x-y)(x^2+y^2+yx+x+y+3)$, it is not really clear that this second polynomial does not have any real solution. Could you please elaborate?